How do I avoid discussions that provoke my aversion to slang words and my friends that use them?
I am a 16 yo teen. I have recently gotten admitted into a new school. My classmates in this school use too much slangs and discuss on topics related to lust too often. My initial socialization attempt with these classmates was by large fruitless as they were interested in topics of lust to which I have clear aversion. In my previous school, similar situations had arisen but I was able to fend them off. But this invited stares that gave me a sense of dumbness. rather than isolating me from such discussions they would intend to further engage me and grill me with those phrases even more. I am experiencing a character decline due to the presence of such people around me.
Now my question is how do I avoid such discussions without really indicating them my dislike with such discussions, while not inviting annoying stares.

How did you put a stop to this in your previous school? What have you done already that apparently didn't work this time?

I my previous school, I made friends that were like minded. So I didn't mind getting harassed by those classmates as I found relief in my friends. But in my new school, all the boys I have talked to in my few days at school, it seems the conversation turns to that fixed direction and literally it seems the language vocabulary they have accumulated over the course of years was one that of slangs. I had some authority in my previous school, but here I am a total newbie. In my previous school, I had made a group of friends and we would generally sit together.

Know every no
Because there's ten-thousand-and-one more for every one.
I encourage you to approach language—common, formal, etymologies, translations, linguistic registries, phraseologies and evolving usages unconventional or otherwise—with the same curiosity that made you interested in "attempts at socialization" so that you know all the more what, when, how, where and who deserves the succinctness, certainty and sterility of your no-slang-no-rhyme-clear-as-blank-stare "No" (without-a-blink).
Aversion is like allergy. It is powerful to know all that you are allergic to. (Literally saves lives).
Equally, it is powerful to understand that not all have the same allergy; some might be immune; and others might allergically react differently, yet are equally reacting in power of active aversion (tolerance).
Let fruit be fruit so that you know what you have strong aversion to and what you don't. Because fruit comes in beauty, desire, and joy (too). And you won't appreciate all the ways it can be put to use for the greater change you hope to see in your own friends—including ones that might be imploding with a smile unbeknownst to all of you (including you) just to avoid those very stares—if you (too) avoid every named and unnamed thing that reeks slang of ugly.
Let the human race be the human race, buddy. You know who you are and that "No" is a complete sentence so make sure nothing slips through its completeness each and every time you say it.

"A cucumber is bitter. Throw it away. There are briars in the road. Turn aside from them. This is enough. Do not add, "And why were such things made in the world?"
— L. G. William Chapman, B.A., LL.B. Not getting along (VIII. 50, trans. George Long on Meditations by Marcus Aurelius)


Hey, I appreciate the first paragraph, I will try looking for phrases that may fit the "what, when, how, where and who deserves the succinctness"  . But the rest were a bit difficult to comprehend. Either way thanks for directing me to the meditations. It seems interesting, ill try reading it.
